# htaccess redirect files of type to php script and pass filename

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a subdirectory on my site containing jpg images, e.g. site.com/files/image1.jpg

I would like to redirect these all to a php script that will handle the delivering of the files. I have tested various rewrite rules but can't seem to get it working right. I almost have the following working, but it seems to only work when the file does NOT exist, e.g. if I enter site.com/files/asdasdasd.jpg it will work, because that file doesn't exist, but image1.jpg exists and the image is immediately delivered for some reason.

P.S. is it best practice to have the .htaccess file and the PHP script in the root directory or in the same subdirectory i.e. 'files'

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ deliver.php?file=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Most likely your rule does not get applied. You have to enable the rewriting module and you have to grant override permission for the rule to get applied.

Comment: The shown `.htaccess` style file will only work in what you cann the `root` folder, since it would not match the request when placed inside the `files` folder. You'd have to modify the pattern for that.

Comment: @arkascha Thanks for the help, I actually tested and it works for files that don't exist like I mentioned, e.g. site.com/files/nofile.jpg will successfully redirect. But if the file exists, it seems to directly serve that instead of redirecting.

Comment: A general hint: if you have access to the http server configuration, then place the rules there instead. `.htaccess` style files are notoriously error prone, hard to setup, harder to debug and they _really_ slow the server down. They should only be used if you really have no other option.

Comment: That makes little sense to me, sorry, either the rule does get applied or it does not. There is no "sometimes" in that.

Comment: Yes, I'm puzzled too. The PHP handler script I'm using outputs some debug information and it's definitely the case where if the file exists its simply being delivered, but if the file doesn't exist the handler script is being called. @arkascha

Comment: Oh, this could be a caching issue on the client side. Please clear your browsers cache and try again with existing files.

Comment: @arkascha that doesn't seem to be an issue, tried clearing the cache and tried other browsers to no avail

Comment: A proxy in between maybe? Try checking your http servers access log file if the requests are _really_ served from the server. And try accessing an image you never reusted before.